# How to access themed images

Tags: web-part, 2013, theme

we created an own color-palette and theme and uploaded that to our server.
So far so good - now we try to use some of the sharepoint default images (like the big plus sign above lists for adding elements) inside of a custom visual webpart.

The question is: how do we get the location of the themed pngs?
I tried this here but had to notice, that the bunch of numbers changes:

```
<span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20">
  <img class="ms-list-addnew-img20" id="idHomePageNewItem-img"
       src="<%: Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/theme/Themed/B33ABC55/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng") %>?ctag=2"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities to get the ThemedImageUrl of the *spcommon.png* File. You can use C# Code and the Method **GetThemedImageUrl()** which was allready mentioned.

But SharePoint 2013 also provides a new Control called [ThemedForegroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.themedforegroundimage.aspx). Take a look how to use it:

```
<SharePoint:ThemedForegroundImage ThemeKey="spcommon" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png" runat="server" CssClass="my-class" ID="myElementId" />
```

And the following HTML is the Result of this Control:

```
<img id="myElementId" class="my-class" src="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/1D65FA0B/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=0" />
```

For those how loves JavaScript. Yes it is also possible to get the ThemedImageUrl using JavaScript. Therefore you have to call the following Method which return the requested Url:

```
GetThemedImageUrl('spcommon.png')
```

I have written a blogpost about this topic. But this post is currently only available in German. But there you will find some screenshots.

http://msscorner.de/2013/07/11/how-to-use-a-themable-sharepoint-image/

Comment: That's a nice solution, too :) Since i like that more than mine, you get the credit.

Comment: Thanks! It is also possible to get the ThemedImageUrl using JavaScript. You only have to call the following Method which return the Url: GetThemedImageUrl('spcommon.png')

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little bit into Sharepoint Theming I found the following gem:

```
SPUtility.GetThemedImageUrl(SPUtility.ContextImagesRoot + "spcommon.png", "spcommon")
```

This will return a correctly themed image as SP itself will use it above lists.

[MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getthemedimageurl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

working with this code:

```
SPUtility.GetThemedImageUrl(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPUtility.ContextImagesRoot, "spcommon.png"), "spcommon");
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just inspect that icon that i need

[image: How to access themed images sharepoint]
then copy > copyOuterHTML

```
<span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20"><img id="idHomePageNewItem-img" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=43#ThemeKey=" class="ms-list-addnew-img20"></span>
```

then use your own custom images by custom css